i18n layout change is not the same in android and ios in react-native expo
In my app, I support two languages via i18n (English and Arabic). I have this weird problem with my local environment when using expo-go and my production environment (the installed apps via the app stores) don't correspond. For example, in my android local development with expo-go, the texts in my header are a mess in Arabic, but when I use the android prod version (the one I installed via the play store), that same header is fixed, I don't have any issues with it.
Header in Android expo-go

And that's not only it, my android and ios prod versions don't correspond as well. Unfortunately I don't have an apple device to test my app in expo-go, but this is what I get for the header in the prod versions of my app:
Header in Android (Clean, no problem)

Header in IOS (Problematic). I got this picture from my friend's iphone

Can someone tell me why is there such a notable difference and what I'm I doing wrong? I have these kind of issues all throughout my app?
Here's my Header component code, maybe from this someone can find the cause of issue
import React, {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ViewStyle} from 'react-native';
import {theme} from '../constants';
import {useAppNavigation} from '../hooks';
import {Feather} from "@expo/vector-icons";

type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
    title?: string;
    goBack?: boolean;
    style?: ViewStyle;
    skip?: boolean;
    skipText?: string;
    skipOnPress?: () => void;
    onBackPress?: () => void;
    admin?: boolean;
}>;

const Header = ({
                    title,
                    style,
                    goBack,
                    skip,
                    skipText,
                    skipOnPress,
                    onBackPress,
                }: Props) => {
    const navigation = useAppNavigation();

    const goPreviousPage = () => {
        if (onBackPress) {
            onBackPress();
        } else if (navigation.canGoBack()) {
            navigation.goBack();
        } else {
            // Go back home page
            navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{name: 'TabNavigator'}],
            });
        }
    }

    const renderGoBack = () => {
        if (goBack) {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: 10,
                        marginRight: 10,
                        borderRadius: 24,
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        marginHorizontal: 3,
                        backgroundColor: theme.colors.mainColor,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                    onPress={goPreviousPage}
                >
                    <View style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                        <Feather name="arrow-left" size={24} color={theme.colors.white}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }

        return null;
    };

    const renderSkipText = () => {
        if (skip) {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                        right: 0,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        paddingHorizontal: 20,
                    }}
                    onPress={skipOnPress}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: theme.colors.textColor,
                            fontWeight: 400
                        }}
                    >
                        {skipText}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
        return null;
    };

    const renderTitle = () => {
        if (title) {
            return (
                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        color: theme.colors.mainColor,
                        width: "100%",
                        left: goBack ? 70 : 28
                    }}
                    numberOfLines={1}
                >
                    {title}
                </Text>
            );
        }

        return null;
    };

    const containerStyle: ViewStyle = {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 52,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.transparent,
        ...style,
    };

    return (
        <View style={{...containerStyle}}>
            {renderGoBack()}
            {renderTitle()}
            {renderSkipText()}
        </View>
    );
};

export default Header;

And this is my i18n.ts config
import i18n, {LanguageDetectorAsyncModule} from 'i18next';
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import en from './locales/en/translation.json';
import fr from './locales/fr/translation.json';
import ar from './locales/ar/translation.json';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {reloadAppAsync} from "expo";

const resources = {
    en: {translation: en},
    ar: {translation: ar},
    fr: {translation: fr},
};

const languageCodeKey = "languageCode";

const languageDetector: LanguageDetectorAsyncModule = {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    // @ts-ignore
    detect: async (callback: (language: string) => void): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            // If not null in the async storage, return it
            const languageCode = await AsyncStorage.getItem(languageCodeKey);
            if (languageCode) {
                return callback(languageCode);
            }
            // Return the device's default language or fallback to Arabic
            const defaultLanguageCode = Localization.getLocales()[0]?.languageCode || 'ar';
            return callback(defaultLanguageCode);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error detecting language:', error);
            callback('ar');
        }
    },
    init: () => {
    },
    cacheUserLanguage: async (languageCode: string) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(languageCodeKey, languageCode);
            const isRTL = i18n.language === 'ar';
            if (I18nManager.isRTL !== isRTL) {
                I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
                I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);
                await reloadAppAsync();
            }
        } catch
            (error) {
            console.error('Error caching language:', error);
        }
    }
};

i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .init({
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
        resources,
        fallbackLng: 'ar',
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    })
    .then(() => {
        const isRTL = i18n.language === 'ar';
        I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
        I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error}`));

export default i18n;

I'm using forceRTL and allowRTL like suggested in countless tutorials
EDIT: This is how it looks in English in all my android versions (no problem whatsoever)

